# Android Manifest not accepting changes

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm writing a app in android studio 0.8.14(latest) and I am trying to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

After adding the permission I clean, rebuild and make the project but I still get error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getTasks() from pid=6608, uid=10061 requires android.permission.GET_TASKS
```

Another peculiar thing is if I remove any of my current permissions(like "android.permission.WR") the app still runs fine like I didn't change a thing

Another permission that isn't working is REORDER_TASKS, but I think it will be fixed once the manifest applies permissions.

This permission doesn't require any special permission as per: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Below is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="*package*" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WR" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Put your `uses-permission` tag outside `application` tag**

From [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html):

```
CONTAINED IN:
   <manifest>
```

Like this.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="*package*" >

    <!-- put it here -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2">        

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```